# Using MKStoreKit to download purchased content

Tags: ios, mkstorekit

I'm looking at using MKStoreKit to handle in-app purchases, Server Product Model, non-consumables, where a product ID corresponds to one purchased data file.

The default server script to verify product id's, verifyProduct.php, returns YES or NO strings, simply indicating whether or not a receipt is valid.  Instead of returning a YES value, is it correct to modify the script to return a content URL for the given product id, so the device can download the purchased content?

Are there any examples of initiating a download from a URL received this way?  I'm trying to understand how clicking a Buy button in a table of products starts a download for the selected row once the purchase has completed successfully.

Thanks for any help

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MKStoreKit calls your server's verifyProduct.php, and a return value of YES will cause MKSK to invoke verifyReceiptOnComplete's completionBlock. So you should implement that in your client code, instead of changing the server API.